# Set DateEdit with a date 3 years ahead of other DateEdit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript function with does the following;

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="txd_DOM" runat="server" Height="16px" Theme="MetropolisBlue" ClientInstanceName ="txd_DOM">
  <ClientSideEvents DateChanged="function(s, e) {
                  txt_Testing_Date.SetDate(txd_DOM.GetDate());
                                 }"/>
                        </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

It Sets a datedit box to the same date as another date edit.
However I want it to set the date for txt_Testing_Date to 3 years ahead of the date in txd_DOM

I'm relatively new to this so any Help would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiarized with the technology you are using but try this, please:

```
   <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="txd_DOM" runat="server" Height="16px" Theme="MetropolisBlue" ClientInstanceName ="txd_DOM">
      <ClientSideEvents DateChanged="
            function(s, e) {
                 var date = txd_DOM.GetDate();
                 var newDate = new Date(date.getFullYear() + 3, date.getMonth(), date.getDay());

                 txt_Testing_Date.SetDate(newDate.getDate());
            }"/>
   </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

Comment: You sent me on the right lines.
It was actually;
function(s, e) {
 var date = txd_DOM.GetDate();
var newDate = new Date(date.getFullYear() + 3,                  date.getMonth(), date.getDay());
txt_Testing_Date.SetDate(newDate);
}